# Expo App keep crashing on scan, every single time

Tags: react-native, expo

I am working on a React Native app, using the expo app to see the output while working.
After installing a react-native-SVG package my expo app keeps crashing every single time I scan the QR code to see the App result on my device. This never happened before. I also uninstalled that specific package and I still face the same problem.

When I visualize the output in a web browser, it works without errors.

Any suggestions? I am running out of solutions at the moment.

Comment: Did you rebuild your app after installing react-native-svg? It has native dependencies so it might be that.

Comment: I don't want to use react-native-svg anymore, I tried to "yarn" the project again but nothing works.

Comment: @EdoardoTrotta undo changes using `git` ... the module must be auto-linked + expo is already shipped with a specific version of react-native-svg

Comment: I found out what was the issue. 

I was styling a component using rem instead of px, that was causing the crash. Insane, but that was it.

Comment: @ Edoardo Trotta How did you fix these errors i have the same problem?

Comment: @john if you're using styling, be sure to use "px" instead of "rem". That was causing the instant crash of my instance.